data suppression with power bi
Is it possible to have suppression be reflected in a stacked column chart?
So if some value is greater than 0 and fewer than 10, have the chart label in a stacked column chart display the character "S"? Thank you.

Can you please add some sample data with your expected output?

This is the sample data I used for test



Column1
Column2




a
5


b
15


c
20



you can create a measure
Measure = iF(
    sum('Table'[Column2])>0 && sum('Table'[Column2])<10,
    "S",
    FORMAT(sum('Table'[Column2]),"#.##")
)

then add this measure to data details

